# Where am I doing wrong in getting the outputs?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Qa2QeArray2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfAircrafts;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter num Of Aircrafts : ");
        numOfAircrafts = sc.nextInt();
        //To Determine the length of the Array
        String[] stringArray = new String[numOfAircrafts];
        System.out.println("Please enter the names of the Aircrafts : ");
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfAircrafts; i++)
        {
            stringArray[i] = sc.next();
        }
        //To insert the string values to the Array
        double[] doubleArray = new double[numOfAircrafts];
        System.out.println("Please enter the shipment rate through each aircraft carrier : ");
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfAircrafts; i++)
        {
            doubleArray[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        //To insert the double values to the Array
        String[] dubArr = new String [stringArray.length * doubleArray.length];

        for (int x = 0; x < stringArray.length ; x++) 
            for (int y = 0; y < doubleArray.length ; y++) {

        System.out.println(stringArray[x] + " \t " + doubleArray[y]); 
            }
    }

}
```

I am looking for o/p as below

```
Emirates     20.89
Indigo       10.34
```

But I am getting o/p as

```
Emirates     20.89
Emirates     10.34
Indigo       20.89
Indigo       10.34
```

Comment: You have two (nested) loops printing output. You only need one.

Comment: `stringArray` has two elements, and `doubleArray` has two elements, so a nested loop will produce 4 results.  Did you mean to loop over only one of them?  This also sounds like a good opportunity to replace separate arrays with a single array of a custom object.  Then just loop over that array.

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested loops that are running.
The `x` loop and `y` loop.
When `x=0` prints the values and again when `x=1`
it prints values.
That is why you are getting output two times.

Remove one loop and you are good to go.